# Уменьшение времени на обход двух изображений при сравнении

Tags: java, android

Есть класс, где происходит сравнение двух изображений Bitmap.

```
public boolean compareImages() {

    int f = 20;
    int w1 = Math.min(50, one.getWidth() - two.getWidth());
    int h1 = Math.min(50, one.getHeight() - two.getHeight());
    int w2 = Math.min(5, one.getWidth() - two.getWidth());
    int h2 = Math.min(5, one.getHeight() - two.getHeight());

    for (int i = 0; i <= one.getWidth() - two.getWidth(); i += f) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= one.getHeight() - two.getHeight(); j += f) {
            compareSubset(i, j, f);
        }
    }

    one = Bitmap.createBitmap(one, Math.max(0, x - w1), Math.max(0, y - h1),
            Math.min(two.getWidth() + w1, one.getWidth() - x + w1),
            Math.min(two.getHeight() + h1, one.getHeight() - y + h1));
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    difference = 0;
    f = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i <= one.getWidth() - two.getWidth(); i += f) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= one.getHeight() - two.getHeight(); j += f) {
            compareSubset(i, j, f);
        }
    }
    one = Bitmap.createBitmap(one, Math.max(0, x - w2), Math.max(0, y - h2),
            Math.min(two.getWidth() + w2, one.getWidth() - x + w2),
            Math.min(two.getHeight() + h2, one.getHeight() - y + h2));
    f = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= one.getWidth() - two.getWidth(); i += f) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= one.getHeight() - two.getHeight(); j += f) {
            compareSubset(i, j, f);
        }
    }
    return difference < 0.15;
}

private void compareSubset(int a, int b, int f) {
        double diff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < two.getWidth(); i += f) {
            for (int j = 0; j < two.getHeight(); j += f) {
                int onepx = one.getPixel(i + a, j + b);
                int twopx = two.getPixel(i, j);
                int r1 = (onepx >> 16);
                int g1 = (onepx >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b1 = (onepx) & 0xff;
                int r2 = (twopx >> 16);
                int g2 = (twopx >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b2 = (twopx) & 0xff;
                diff += (Math.abs(r1 - r2) + Math.abs(g1 - g2) + Math.abs(b1
                        - b2)) / 3.0 / 255.0;
            }
        }
        double percentDiff = diff * f * f / (two.getWidth() * two.getHeight());
        if (percentDiff < difference || difference == 0) {
            difference = percentDiff;
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }
}
```

Как я понимаю здесь происходит линейный проход по пикселям, что приводит к большим временным затратам. Какой алгоритм стоит здесь использовать, чтобы уменьшить затраты времени на обход?

Comment: По идее вызов `Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer()` или `Bitmap.getPixels()` и дальнейшее сравнение уже буферов должно быть быстрее

Comment: А еще есть `Bitmap.sameAs()`

Comment: У меня просто изображения могут быть немного сдвинуты в сторону, но при этом содержать один и тот же контент

Comment: И вы не знаете смещения? Тогда задача вообще не так решается

Comment: Да, согласен с @Anton Shchyrov, вам нужно использовать что-то инное, а именно нейронные сети и как варик TensorFlow, где нужно будет обучить модель, а потом её использовать. И как вариант, дешевле купить у кого-то кто этим реально занимается. Если же у вас достаточно времени можно и самому, ведь задача достаточно интересная.